# How to randomly select one item from every list of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, random

I have a dictionary:

```
>>> print(dict)
{'gs': ['bags', 'begs', 'bogs'],
 'le': ['Cole', 'Dale', 'Dole'],
 'll': ['Ball', 'Bell', 'Bill']}
```

For every single key I want to pick only one word (randomly) from its list.
The output would be like:

```
{'gs': begs, 'le': 'Cole', 'll': 'Bill'}
```

and so on.

I have tried loads of things but none has given me a word for every key of the dictionary. Is there a simple way of doing that?

Comment: _this_ (my edit) is what a [mcve] should look like.

Answer (score 5):

just use `random.choice` on the values of the dictionary, rebuilding a dict comprehension with only 1 name as value

```
import random
d = {'gs': ['bags', 'begs', 'bogs'],
'le': ['Cole', 'Dale', 'Dole'],
'll': ['Ball', 'Bell', 'Bill']}


result = {k:random.choice(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

one output:

```
{'gs': 'bogs', 'le': 'Dale', 'll': 'Bell'}
```

Comment: Missed out answering this one because I was too busy fixing the question :D ++

Comment: the only problem I see in this is that it has to iterate through the entire dictionary.  I like the idea of just getting the 'len()' of keys and then randomly picking an index number.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish not sure what you mean; this is what OP wants. What you describe is not better than this.

Comment: `choice` doesn't iterate. It picks an index in the values list, except that it's transparent.

Comment: That is absolutely not true.  `{k:random.choice(v) for k,v in d.items()}` iterates through the entire dictionary first.

Comment: of course, how to pick a value in each list without that? `choice` doesn't iterate. We're not talking about the same thing

Comment: Oh wait you are right, i was misreading the goal.  My bad.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think one easy way would be to pick a random number between 0 and the length of each list and then picking the item that corresponds to that index! Just iterate through the dictionary's keys (using `list(yourdictionary)`), get each list, find its length, choose the random number and finally get the element.